# Tensor equal to zero everywhere except in a dynamic rectangle

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given `a, b, c, d` 4 tensors of type `tf.int` and shape `[1]`, what's the easiest way to get a tensor `X` such that:

- `X` has shape `[h, w]`,
- `X` is `0` everywhere except between the rows `a < b` and the columns `c < d` where it's equal to `1`.

Comment: There's a solution which is not that elegant using `tf.py_func`. I'm all ears to more tensorflow-like solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.meshgrid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/meshgrid) to create an array of row and column indices. Then apply [logical operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/control_flow_ops#Logical_Operators) on the index arrays to get the mask for where the ones should be. Finally, [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) can be used to build up the requested tensor `X`.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
h = 5
w = 6

a = 1
b = 3
c = 2
d = 4

cols, rows = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(w), tf.range(h))
mask_rows = tf.logical_and( tf.less(rows, b), tf.greater_equal(rows, a))
mask_cols = tf.logical_and( tf.less(cols, d), tf.greater_equal(cols, c))
mask = tf.logical_and(mask_rows, mask_cols)

X = tf.where(mask, tf.ones([h,w], tf.float32), tf.zeros([h,w], tf.float32))
```

Verify the outputs:

```
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(cols))
print(sess.run(rows))
print(sess.run(X))
```

Output for `cols`:

```
[[0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]]
```

Output for `rows`

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4]]
```

Output for `X`

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```